# Can't understand 3D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Assume 
`double[][][] x = new double[4][5][6]`, why `x.length, x[2].length`, and `x[0][0].length` are 4, 5, and 6 ? Why `[0][0].length` is 6?

Comment: `why [0][0].length is 6??`. Think of it this way. You have `x`, `x` is an array of 4 elements `(x.length;)`, each element in x is an array of 5 elements `(x[i].length;)` and each element in there is an array of 6 elements `(x[i][i].length;)`. To make it clearer, the length of even `x[2][3].length` is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `new double[4][5][6]` what you have is 20 arrays of length 6.  They are addressable as:

```
x[0][0] // array of length 6
x[0][1] // another array of length 6 here
x[0][2] // etc...
x[0][3]
x[0][4]
x[1][0]
x[1][1]
x[1][2]
x[1][3]
x[1][4]
x[2][0]
x[2][1]
x[2][2]
x[2][3]
x[2][4]
x[3][0]
x[3][1]
x[3][2]
x[3][3]
x[3][4]
```

Answer (score 5):

To visualize a three-dimensional array, and to comprehend its length, you can think of it in terms of literal physical dimensions (remember the book [Flat Land](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)?).

One object:

```
.
```

An array of objects:

```
.............
```

The length of this array (`array.length`) is how many elements, or dots, counting from left to right.

A two-dimensional array of objects:

```
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
```

Each element in the previous array now has its own array, going down. The length of the first element in this array (`array[0].length`, the top-left-most) is counting the dots top to bottom.

A three dimensional array is like a cube (this is all assuming uniform lengths among elements)

```
.............
............. .
............. . .
............. . . .
............. . . .
............. . . .
  . . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . . ..
    . . . . . . . .
```

Each element in the previous array now has *its* own array (going *deep* "into" the screen). The length of the first element in ***this*** array (`array[0][0].length`, the top-left-most element) is the number of dots deep.

Not once have I (directly) used a three dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array such as double[] x = new double[5] you are saying you want a 5-long array of double, i.e.

```
    (type) x = new (type)[size];
```

So when you declare double[][][] x = new double[4][5][6] you are saying you want a 6-long array of double[][]:

```
    (double[][])[] x = new (double[4][5])[6];
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with multi-dimensional arrays, it is useful to think of them as an "array-of-arrays." That is to say, `double[]` is an array of `doubles`, `double[][]` would be an array of `double[]` and `double[][][]` is an array made of arrays of arrays of doubles. So let's break down your example:

```
double[][][] x = new double[4][5][6];
```

Working backwards, we can think of this as being an array of 6 arrays of `double[][]`, each of which contains 5 arrays of `double[]`. Each of those arrays contains 4 doubles. Confused yet?

Another thing that might help to see the relationship is to write this using parentheses:

```
(((double[])[])[])
```

Now, when you access `x[2]`, you are actually retrieving an array of arrays at index `2` of `x`, and that array has length 5.

When you access `x[0][0]`, this is *still* just another array (remember, we build up our array as an array of arrays), which you declared in your `new` statement to have length `6`. That is to say, `x[0][0]` will not contain a number, but will contain array of type `double[][]`, which has a length of `6`.